# Approach to simplify using Partial Fraction Decomposition

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Can anyone suggest an approach to simplify this closed form generating function using partial fraction decomposition?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would break the fraction up into simpler bits first to do all the cancellation you obviously can. Then if you really want partial fractions, you will also need to factorise the cubic in the denominator.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha Shows this simplification:   [1]: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify,%20%289%281-4z%29%281-z%5E2%29%2b16z%281-4z%29%281-z%29%5E2%2b208z%5E2%281-4z%29%281-z%29%5E2-9%281-z%29%5E2-81z%281-4z%29%29/%28%281-12z%5E2-16z%5E3%29%281-4z%29%281-z%29%5E2%29/ I hope I input the correct term.

Answer (score 2):

As  Mark Bennet said, you need to factorize the denominator. Once this will be done, you should easily arrive to $$-\frac{14}{2 z+1}-\frac{20}{3 (4 z-1)}+\frac{4}{(2 z+1)^2}-\frac{4}{(4
   z-1)^2}-\frac{13}{3 (z-1)}+\frac{3}{(z-1)^2}$$

Comment: Awesome thanks so much. I'm glad it came out to nice whole numbers :). How would you suggest factorising 1-12z^2-16z^3?

Comment: Well ! There is an "obvious" root at $z=-\frac {1}{2}$. So perform the division to reduce from cubic to quadratic and solve. I let you finishing the work. Remember that, for this kind of problems, the roots are, almost always, quite simple. If this is not clear, just post. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Claude. I'm sorry I have completely forgot how to factorise polynomials of degree 3. Do you have a link I could use to refresh on how to again?

Comment: OK, let me try to explain :$1-12z^2-16z^3$ write $-16(z-z_1)(z-z_2)(z-z_3)$ and you know one of the roots which is $z=-\frac {1}{2}$. Are you able to continue from here ? If not, just post and we shall continue. By the way, for the solution of a cubic, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function. Cheers.

Comment: Unfortunately not Claude. I haven't done maths for a few years and have forgotten this stuff.

Comment: Also how did you get a root as -1/2 as they are not all negative.

Comment: By inspection : $1-12/4+16/8=0$

Comment: Sorry to be stupid but that be a combination of 1/2 and -1/2. Once I get this I think it will make WAY more sense to me. Thanks again for your patience Claude

Comment: You are not stupid and there is no stupid question : $(-1/2)^2=1/4$ and $(-1/2)^3=-1/8$. Is this better ?

Comment: Ohhh yes that makes sense!

Comment: So now I understand that. How do we proceed from your above:

1−12z2−16z3 write −16(z−z1)(z−z2)(z−z3)

Comment: Replace $z_1$ by $-1/2$, develop the product and identify the coefficients in lhs and rhs.

Comment: I am having visualising what you mean. Could you write out the next line for me please?

Comment: Hey Claude, I literally have no idea how you came to your final answer above. Could you please run me through the steps.